# Update spinner afer uppdating data from Drawer

Tags: android

I have a drawer menu with some functions, one of them "update data" is used to update data from SQL server (via Web Services) to the local SQL lite. It works, but I want that when I call "update data" function, automatically update the content of the spinner without reload the activity. 
The "update data" is defined in MainActivity

```
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.updateData:
//call web services
//fetch result and put the updated data in the SQL lite table "data"
        }}
```

The secondary class has the spinner that load the data from the table "data" in the oncreate method.

if I reload the Secondary Activity it works the update, but how can I do to update only the content of the spinner in object?
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Call in invalidate() on the view. I think that should work (or it has some other method for notifying data updates)

Answer (score 0):

setAdapter for your spinner another time.

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

String[] text = new String[2];
text[0] = "test 1";
text[1] = "test 2";
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.YOUR_SPINNER_LAYOUT, text);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```